# How to check "contain" here in IEnumerable list?

Tags: c#, linq

```
bool NonEquijoin(Product product)
{
    var nonEquijoinQuery =
        from p in products
        let catIds = from c in categories
                     select c.ID
        where catIds.Contains(p.CategoryID) == true
        select new { Product = p.Name, CategoryID = p.CategoryID };

    if (nonEquijoinQuery.Contains(product))
    {
        true;
    }
    else
    {
        false;
    }

}
```

In two different object list I have to findout if item of one list contains in the other list then return me those items.After returning it I have to check if givenItem is exists in the returned list then return true otherwise return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool NonEquijoin(Product product)
{
   return (from p in products
        let catIds = from c in categories
                     select c.ID
        where catIds.Contains(p.CategoryID)).Any(a =>a.Name == product.Name);
}
```

side note

`catIds.Contains(p.CategoryID)` return type is bool so don't need to check equality again with bool.